# Determining whether a given function can be considered as a probability function

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Recently I was given the following problem.

The sample space $\Omega = \{ 1, 2, 3, 4 \}$ and the function P is defined as follows:

$$P(\emptyset) = 0, P(\Omega) = 1, P(\{1,2\}) = \frac12, P(\{3,4\}) = \frac12, P(\{3\}) = \frac13, P(\{4\}) = \frac16 , P(\{1,2,3\}) = \frac56, P(\{1,2,4\}) = \frac23.$$

The question is whether $P$ can be considered a probability function.

My issue with this problem is that I am not sure whether it is definitely possible to answer the question. On the one hand, if P is a probability function, then for each two mutually exclusive events the sum of their probabilities should be $1$. In this case, $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3,4\}$ are mutually exclusive events, but $P(\{1\}) + P(\{2,3,4\})$ is not known. On the other hand, there is not enough information to claim the opposite. It seems to me that the question itself is incorrect, but I am not quite sure because I do not have enough experience in probability theory.

So, is $P$ a probability function?

Comment: Probabilities need only be specified for events: which subsets of $\Omega$ are events?

Comment: @kimchilover this is the whole formulation of the question, no additional information is known. I assume that all subsets of $\Omega$ should be considered.

Comment: I thought the question was "Can it be considered to be...", not "Is it". If the former, the answer is yes. If the latter, the answer is we cannot know until the extra information is provided to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly speaking, probability on a sample space $\Omega$ is a function $P:\Sigma\to[0,1]$ defined on a $\color{red}{\sigma\text{-algebra}}$ $\Sigma$ of subsets of $\Omega$. The concept of $\color{red}{\sigma\text{-algebra}}$ means that $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, a subset of the power set of $\Omega$, which has to satisfy several properties:

- contains the empty set;
- closed under complements;
- closed under countable unions and intersections.

(In this example, since we have a finite set $\Omega$, the word "countable" can be omitted.) The elements of $\Sigma$ are the *measurable sets* or the *events*. Note that the definition does **NOT** require all subsets to be events. And if you check, you will see that the subsets for which this $P$ is defined do satisfy these properties, and thus they do form a $\sigma$-algebra.

Once we have a $\sigma$-algebra, we can define a probability function $P$ on it. Such a function also has to satisfy certain axioms, such as $P(X^c)=1-P(X)$, and so on. Note how this axiom of probability hinges on the corresponding axiom of $\sigma$-algebras! Again, you can check that all axioms of probability are satisfied in this example.

So the answer is: **YES**, it is a probability function. The fact that some values, such as $P(\{1\})$ aren't defined only means that they are not admissible events. But in and by itself that doesn't violate the definition.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time to answer the question. You mentioned that "the definition does NOT require all subsets to be events". So, it means that in this case it is implicitly assumed that all subsets for which P is defined are events? What if we decide that all the subsets should be events? Is it a matter of choice?

Comment: as far as I know from the definition of an event, it can be any subset of $\Omega$, so why do we constraint ourselves to those subsets for which the function P is defined?

Comment: @SasunGrigoryan: What is a function? It's a correspondence between its domain and its codomain (such that... the rest doesn't matter right now). A probability $P$ is a function. And just like with any function, we have to define its domain (and codomain) before we define the function itself. So is it a matter of choice? Yes. But whose choice is it? When you're constructing a probability function, you can choose its domain, some $\sigma$-algebra of subsets. But here certain data is given to you. So it's not for you to choose anything. The choice was already made by the author of the question.

Comment: @SasunGrigoryan: For finite or countable sets, we can take all subsets, i.e. the entire power set $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$, as the $\sigma$-algebra of events. (Not so for uncountable sets, as far as I remember.) So yes, we can decide that all subsets are events -- if we're allowed to make any decisions. But here you have to answer the given question; modifying it would be a mistake. Now, it might be a matter of opinion as to what the question means. But in my opinion, the words "$P$ is defined as follows" unambiguously mean that what follows is the complete definition of $P$.

Comment: thanks for your time, I really appreciate it. Sometimes answering purely formulated questions is impossible. In this case would it be correct to say that the actual answer depends on which subsets we consider as events? If yes, then, in my opinion, the formulation of this question lacks important details which are necessary to give the right answer.

Comment: @SasunGrigoryan: I understand your opinion very well, but I have a different opinion. I think this question is sufficiently well-posed, even though it may seem confusing at first. Yes, the answer to such a question does depend on the choice of event. But here the choice has already been made -- it's precisely the ones listed in the definition. And in my opinion, the question states that clearly enough. (Although I can agree that a clarification wouldn't hurt.)

Comment: thank you very much for the discussion. I mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

When I took probability 1, there was a triple $(\Omega, P, \mathcal F)$ consisting of a sample space, a probability measure, and a collection of *events*, subsets of $\Omega$ to which probabilities are assigned.  The domain of $P$ is  $\mathcal F$.

So I'd give a different answer to this question.  The set of events $\mathcal F$ has not been specified, so we can choose it.  If we take $\mathcal F$ to be all subsets of $\Omega$, then Jeremy's answer is correct: at best $P$ is incompletely specified.  But if we take $\mathcal F$ to be generated by just the subsets $\{1,2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}$, then $P$ is a probability on that $\mathcal F$.  If asked, in this case, what $P(\{1\})$ was,  we could answer: ha-ha, $\{1\}$ is not measurable, is not an event, is not in $\mathcal F$, and it doesn't have (and doesn't need) a probability.

Comment: Thanks for spending your time. So, if I understand you right, you suggest that the question can be definitely answered only if it is specified which subsets of $\Omega$ are events?

Comment: Yes.  But the problem wording "can be considered" gives us some permission, I think, to choose the set of events.  (Of course, the set of events has to be as ziporovich describes in his answer.)

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a trick question. Much information is provided about a possible probability function, $P$. Since the sample space is $\omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$, the probability function must describe the probability of each element of the sample space. Events $1$ and $2$ are defined in three of equalaties together. Since the probability of events $1$ and $2$ aren't defined *individually* and they are part of the sample space this probability function $P$ is incomplete and not fully defined.

$P$ is not a probability function.

Comment: thanks for elaborating. So, in general, if I understand it correctly, if P is not defined for all subsets of a sample space, then it cannot be considered a probability function, right?

Comment: @SasunGrigoryan: Wrong.